# Redirect button to django admin auth views

Tags: django, django-admin

I am trying to create a button in my Django navbar to redirect to the admin authentication views and have not manage to find the answer to my question.

I manage to do:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'admin:appname_model_perm' %}">Manage XYZ</a></li>
```

and:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Main view</a></li>
```

but I cannot find a way to create one for admin:auth... Here is what I tried:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'admin:auth' %}">Manage auth</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'admin:authentication' %}">Manage auth</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'admin:authenticate' %}">Manage auth</a></li>
```

Also, is there a way in Django to get a list of all available registered URLs?

Instead of having this quite useless error message:

> Reverse for 'auth' not found. 'auth' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the list of [availalbe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls) Django Admin reverse urls.

```
<li><a href="{% url 'admin:login' %}">Login</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'admin:password_change' %}">Password Change</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'admin:logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Raja, it seems not to reverse urls the "auth" "homepage". I finally used absolute path to do it.